# Avoid Query Client Evaluation error on a query with method definition inside entity class

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, lazy-evaluation

In a **.NET Core 2.1** project, I'm using EF Core with Command pattern (using *MediatR* library) on a SQL Server database.

I setup the project to avoid client query evaluation, by using these settings:

```
var phaseOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PhaseDbContext>().UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("PhaseDbContext"),
        sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions
            .EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 5,
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null))
    .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings
        .Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)) // Disable Client query evaluation
    .Options;
```

Now I get a `QueryClientEvaluationException` with this query:

```
var articleCodes = await PhaseContext.PhaseArticles
    .Where(a => !request.ArticleFamily.HasValue || a.GetArticleFamily() == request.ArticleFamily.Value)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The problem is on the `a.GetArticleFamily()` method call, because that method now is defined as follows, inside the `PhaseArticle` entity class:

```
public class PhaseArticle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public double UnitCost { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalDescription { get; set; }
    public string ExternalCode { get; set;}
    public string ColorCode { get; set;}
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public ArticleFamily GetArticleFamily()
    {
        switch (Family)
        {
            case "CEL":
                return ArticleFamily.Cell;
            case "STR":
                return ArticleFamily.String;
            case "RAW":
                return ArticleFamily.OtherRawMaterial;
            case "SFP":
                return ArticleFamily.SemiFinishedPanel;
            case "FP":
                return ArticleFamily.FinishedPanel;
            default:
                return ArticleFamily.Other;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to know if it is possible to keep the `QueryClientEvaluationWarning` option by somehow refactoring (and probably moving away from the entity class) the GetArticleFamily() method.

#### Update 2019/02/26

@StriplingWarrior I've updated again the code with your suggestion about `ValueConverter()`, but now it is giving this error:

> Cannot convert Lambda expression into a tree of expressions.

#### Update 2019/02/25

Following @StriplingWarrior suggestion, I'm trying to write a custom converter but I'm not able to make my code compile.

The error with the code below is about **return value** of the first `switch` block (it's `string` but it is expected to be an `enum`) and about the expected **input value** of the second switch block (it's a `string` but it is expected to be an `enum`).

This is the code:

```
public static void ApplyPhaseConversions<T>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<PhaseArticle>()
        .Property(e => e.Family)
        .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<ArticleFamily, string> {
            v =>
            {
                switch (v)
                {
                    case ArticleFamily.Cell:
                        return "CEL";
                    case ArticleFamily.String:
                        return "STR";
                    case ArticleFamily.OtherRawMaterial:
                        return "RAW";
                    case ArticleFamily.SemiFinishedPanel:
                        return "SFP";
                    case ArticleFamily.FinishedPanel:
                        return "FP";
                    default:
                        return "";
                }
            },
            v =>
            {
                switch (v)
                {
                    case "CEL":
                        return ArticleFamily.Cell;
                    case "STR":
                        return ArticleFamily.String;
                    case "RAW":
                        return ArticleFamily.OtherRawMaterial;
                    case "SFP":
                        return ArticleFamily.SemiFinishedPanel;
                    case "FP":
                        return ArticleFamily.FinishedPanel;
                    default:
                        return ArticleFamily.Other;
                }
            }});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution was almost there, as also @StriplingWarrior said.

Due to limitations in the C# compiler, such that it can't create expression trees for this code, the solution is to factory the conversion code into methods and then call those in `HasConversion`.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<PhaseArticle>()
        .Property(e => e.Family)
        .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<ArticleFamily, string>(
            v => StringFromArticleFamily(v),
            v => ArticleFamilyFromString(v));
}

private static ArticleFamily ArticleFamilyFromString(string family)
{
    switch (family)
    {
        case "CEL":
            return ArticleFamily.Cell;
        case "STR":
            return ArticleFamily.String;
        case "RAW":
            return ArticleFamily.OtherRawMaterial;
        case "SFP":
            return ArticleFamily.SemiFinishedPanel;
        case "FP":
            return ArticleFamily.FinishedPanel;
        default:
            return ArticleFamily.Other;
    }
}

private static string StringFromArticleFamily(ArticleFamily articleFamily)
{
    switch (articleFamily)
    {
        case ArticleFamily.Cell:
            return "CEL";
        case ArticleFamily.String:
            return "STR";
        case ArticleFamily.OtherRawMaterial:
            return "RAW";
        case ArticleFamily.SemiFinishedPanel:
            return "SFP";
        case ArticleFamily.FinishedPanel:
            return "FP";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using `GetArticleFamily()` to convert between the database values and your C# enums. EF Core has a built-in feature called Value Conversions which is meant to address this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

You should be able to define a ValueConverter to translate to and from `ArticleFamily` values, and then change the type of the `Family` property to `ArticleFamily`, and use that property in your query:

```
var articleCodes = await PhaseContext.PhaseArticles
    .Where(a => !request.ArticleFamily.HasValue || a.Family == request.ArticleFamily.Value)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

PS--I'm not sure what kind of query the code above will produce, but it might be better to compose your query like this:

```
var articleQuery = PhaseContext.PhaseArticles.AsQueryable();
if(request.ArticleFamily.HasValue)
{
    articleQuery = articleQuery.Where(a => a.Family == request.ArticleFamily.Value);
}
var articleCodes = await articleQuery.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: what is the point of running this query if request.ArticleFamily is null? The same is if the request is null.

Comment: @GoldenAge: It looks like `request.ArticleFamily` is an optional filter. If it's null then you return all `PhaseArticles`.

Comment: (I'm guessing that `request` should never be null. It's probably getting initialized from a JSON object that's getting sent from a client to a Web API action.)

Comment: In practice, I agree. It was more like a theoretical digression because I'm not able to see the full implementation of the described problem :)

Comment: so I've made a check and there is such an option when the request object is `null`. I edited my answer.

Comment: @GoldenAge Using ValueConverter is the right EF Core solution for this (client to db mapping)problem. It will do automatically the similar conversion and same query as what you are doing manually. The conditional .`Where` part is not necessary though, because EF Core performs constant predicate elimination, so the generated queries will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification about constant predicate elimination, Ivan. I learned something new. :-)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I know `ValueConverter` of EF Core and I'm already using it for other simple conversions from enums to string, but in those cases I'm writing to the db the same string value of the enum. In this case I need a switch, or anyway some conversion logic, from enum to string and vice-versa. I've updated the code because it gives me errors.

Comment: @CheshireCat: It looks like you've got the right idea using switch statements in the value converter, but looking at the method signatures for the [HasConversion method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder.hasconversion?view=efcore-2.1) I'm pretty sure you need to pass in a `new ValueConverter<ArticleFamily, string>()` rather than passing those conversion delegates directly as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new variable and transfer the request.ArticleFamily.Value result so it can return ArticleFamily.Cell or ArticleFamily.String and then run the query

e.g.

```
if(request != null && !request.ArticleFamily.HasValue)
// or throw an exception here
 return ...;

ArticleFamily newVariable = (ArticleFamily)Enum.Parse(typeof(ArticleFamily), request.ArticleFamily);
var articleCodes = await PhaseContext.PhaseArticles
    .Where(a => a.Family == newVariable)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The validation of the method's parameters should be done before running the query. Another thing is what happens if the request is `null`?

**Edit**

There is also a need to validate the `request` object. There can be a case when you make a typo or mistake in structure(you forget to add a comma after defining a value of field) of the JSON object that you send to the API. In such a case, the request object would have a `null` value so there is a need to validate such a behavior. E.g. you can add

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

in the action of your controller to validate the whole request body. The client will receive the proper error message.