# Can't use LINQ in EF Where expression for lambda property

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I changed the LINQ expression like this.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Thing>> Get(bool all)
{
  List<Thing> output = await Context.Things
    //.Where(_ => all || _.DeletedOn == null && _.Deletedon < DateTime.Now)
    .Where(_ => all || _.Active)
    .ToListAsync();
  return output;
}
```

Apparently, it caused the following error.

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Where(l => False || l.Active)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Well, I **do have** a call to *AsListAsync()* and I'm a bit buffeled that such a simple conditional wasn't interpretable by .NET Core EF. I suspect I might be missing something else.

The class *Thing* looks like this.

```
class Thing
{
  ...
  public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
  public Active => DeletedOn == null && DeletedOn < DateTime.Now.
}
```

Checking the [provided link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038) gave me nothing.

Comment: You have a logic issue because the condition Active => DeletedOn == null && DeletedOn < DateTime.Now will always return false.

Comment: @lior Correct. But is that the cause of the exception?!

Comment: What does this statement mean .`Where(_ => all`

Comment: EF has limitation when using computed properties, as it has a hard time to find what "sits" behind them. It basically tries to map property name (i.e. Active) to database columns, which fails and results with the error. To cut it short, I think you'll have to stick with the first option.

Comment: How can it be both null *and* less than now?
As for your error message, linq cant translate your bool Active property since it is not an expression.

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten no the logic issue is not the cause of the exception. See my answer below.

Comment: . Correction! your issue is your using computed values... these will not work with linq to sql.

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you familiar with in-line LINQ? Is the lambda expression confusing? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [breaking changes in .Net core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)

One solution (though not advised) could be the following:

> If a query can't be fully translated, then either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or use AsEnumerable(), ToList(), or similar to explicitly bring data back to the client where it can then be further processed using LINQ-to-Objects.

So as it would happen before, get the dbset with a translatable query and filter later on with whatever C# linq to Objects magic you'd like.

Without having tested it, I believe that EF can't translate your [Expression bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-set-statements). Did it work when you tried with the following?

```
   .Where(_ => all || _.DeletedOn == null && _.Deletedon < DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: What would be the SQL for  `.Where(_ => all)`

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat I guess `1 = 1` if `all = true`

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat It would return **all** the elements, regardless of whether they've been soft deleted or not. In SQL: *select \**, i.e. no *where* condition.

Comment: This is a real gotcha. I understand the rationale behind it. Although, I'd prefer to let me still use my stuff in the potentially costly way. In many cases, DRY will be affected with no, or little, gain in performance. Me not like. But +1 for the link and spot-on info.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, the expression bodied member `getter` is actually regarded a method call, which [can't be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54830603/314291) by a Linq QueryProvider into native SQL, so you'll need to again undo your 'DRY' code and instead expand the predicate logic in the `Active` property directly into your Linq Query, or alternately you would need to pass the entire Expression Tree or IQueryable to a method like `Active` so that it could compose the predicate into it (which seems overkill).

Also, as per comments, there's a logical issue - `_.DeletedOn == null && _.Deletedon < DateTime.Now` will return false, meaning the query is then all or nothing based on the value of the `all` parameter. At a guess, you're looking for a conditionally applied 'logical delete' filter, which also allows for future dated deletion, i.e. any record which hasn't yet been deleted is to be regarded as active, or any record which has a null deletion date hasn't been deleted at all.

And finally, for most RDBMS, especially SQL Server, it is usually not a good idea to add a hard coded predicate (like `all`) into a `WHERE` filter, as this can mess with the [query plan caching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/160037/9433). In your case, the `all` flag filtering logic simply decides whether you want to include logically `Deleted` data or not. IMO, I would instead [conditionally compose the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11465973/314291) like follows to avoid doing unnecessary filtering in SQL.

Putting this all together, the query would be:

```
var query = Context.Things;
if (!all)
{
   query = query.Where(t => t.DeletedOn == null || t.Deletedon > DateTime.Now)
}
var output = await query
   .ToListAsync();
return output;
```

Comment: Last comment - by convention, OP shouldn't use `_` as a used lambda parameter, as it repurposed in many FP languages to indicate a [discarded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) parameter.

Comment: You should move the comment to be a part of your reply. I was totally unaware of the convention (great link BTW) and was using underscore due to lack of imagination. The underscore is the new black (of variable naming, that is). Or so I thought...

Comment: Yup. Principal of least astonishment - make sure the next guy can read your code with the fewest grey hairs. Best convention I've found to date is Sql table aliasing  - first letter of the entity name(s) hence t for Things. So... about that logical delete logic..?

Comment: Ah, you mean the "bug" that people spotted out? In the actual code, it's actually much more complicated expression consisting of several conditions (all relating to the dates of deletion, creation and latest change. I shorted it down while trying to troubleshoot and missed that I introduced a "bug". What that what you referred to?

Comment: Oh, I just realized two weird things with the *first letter convention* in lambda expressions. I sat down to refactor, adapting to the convention. Then I hit two spots that are... well... less optimal. In my project, I have an entity called *Licence*. It looks terrible when I go *.Where(l=>...)*. That's the first thing. The second is that I also have an entity called *Licensee*, nesting the former. So in my code I have *.Where(l1=>l1.Select(l2=>...))*. What's your thought on how to approach it in a way causing the least grey hairs?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the expression body in the public field Active.
EF could not translate this expression `Active => DeletedOn == null && DeletedOn < DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync() before filtering the records i.e. in this case before **Where** condition.